# How to assign values in int type Array[,] from a combobox items

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

for example

```
Array[3,4];

Array[0,0] = Combobox.items[0];

     .
     .
     .

Array[2,3] = Combobox.items[12];


        int sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Columns; j++)
            {
                Array[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(Allocation_Combo.Items[sum+j]);
            }
            sum = sum + 1;
        }
```

i have tried this code but it is not working...may be error in it ...??

Comment: i have done everything but don't able to store them in Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?  The relationship between array coordinates and combobox item indexes is not immediately apparent, since `Array[2,3]` would represent index 9 in the list, not 8, as you have.  But here goes:

```
int index = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        Array[x, y] = Combobox.Items[index++];
```

Comment: What is the relationship between array coordinates and combobox items?  Neither (2*3 + 3) nor (2 + 3*4) are equal to 8.